# If there is only 1 item in the Primary Navigation, is it possibly to have no Primary Navigation at all?

Tags: navigation, categorization

I am currently working on a website that showcases articles. The majority of them are currently sitting in the homepage and a few more are sitting in another section. However other than that particular section there are no other sections meaning that there is only 1 item in the Primary Navigation. Having 1 item there seems very strange. Are there any precedents where a website has no primary navigation?

Comment: Shouldn't both the homepage and the other section be in the primary navigation?  Giving it two items?

Comment: As long as there is more than one section there should always be more than one nav item. The users needs to know where they are if they are not on the home page and they need to know how to get back from wherever they are TO the homepage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users expect a way to get back to the home page of a website.  They will be confused if they are not able to find this.

As long as your site has more than just one view, you need a clear way to get back to the initial view of the site.

If your site is very simple and flat, you could handle this with something other than a traditional menu.  For example:

- A clickable/tappable site logo.
- A single button such as "back" or "return".
- A close button (e.g. to close an article and go back to the main view).

However, your use case suggests at least a basic hierarchy, since you have a home page, then "sections" and "articles".  This implies that a more traditional navigation may make sense, allowing you to go to one of the sections.

Another thing to consider is scalability for the future.  You have one subsection now.  Might this imply that you will need more subsections later as content is added?  You wouldn't want minor content additions to the site to require a major redesign to the navigation.

Answer (score 0):

If you think “Navigation” means “Menu” and every website needs one, that is not the case. Navigation means the possibility to go from A to B. Google Search is also just a page with results and pagination (not taking into account the other things Google offer apart from the search site). It sounds like your website is a very simple one, treat it as such. Don't overthink menu's, navigation bars, headers etc. What's common on the web doesn't always work in every situation. I think Google Search is a good example of that.

Comment: Google's home search page has a menu with 12 top-level options!  Plus other stuff like log in and notifications.  I'm not sure that this is the best example...

Comment: I agree it’s not the best example, it was just one of the first I could think of. Google Search has indeed navigation options, but I was pointing to the simplicity regarding the main functionality; a search field, results and pagination. I’m thinking of adding a better example when I have time for it.